# How to avoid auto-zoom / scale problem with Chrome in iOs

Tags: ios, google-chrome, cross-browser, zooming

I did some testing on a client update for a Cargo Collective site.

http://thomasjpg.com

A Contact form was included for 480px width (mobile) and it sits at the foot of the page (see attachment).

I don't know how to keep it at scale when the input is focused using Chrome. Currently the viewport zooms out rendering the Contact form virtually useless.

In Safari the behaviour does not occur, and I would like to replicate this experience in Chrome.

Having done some A/B testing on a different page (with and without the 3x image grid rows included above the Contact form) I recognise that Chrome only behaves this way once the Viewport has a natural vertical overflow occurring.

[What happens with Chrome in iOs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVpgb.jpg)

[How it should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okVTn.png)